# Crypto++ can't build Qt Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-c++, crypto++

I am currently trying to run Crypto++ in my Qt Application. But it does not work. Hopefully somebody of you knows whats wrong, because I have not figured it out and I am on this for 3 days now.

To concentrate the problem, I have created a test app. Holding this code: http://pastebin.com/1XMARtds taken from http://programmingknowledgeblog.blogspot.de/2013/04/compiling-and-integrating-crypto-into.html

My .pro looks like this:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Savor_V100/libraries/ -lcryptlib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Savor_V100/libraries/ -lcryptlibd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Savor_V100/libraries/ -lcryptlib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../Savor_V100/includes/cryptopp562
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../Savor_V100/includes/cryptopp562
```

I have compiled the library with MS Visual Studio 2012. 
When I use these settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSB6M.png

I get a single 50mb-ish .lib file.

When I then try to build my application in Qt Creator (5.0.2) I get the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXNj0.png

A lot of:

```
cryptlib.lib(cryptlib.obj):-1: error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in main.obj
```

It also says: File not found: cryptlib.lib(cryptlib.obj)

If I put the .obj files in the same folder as the .lib file I get rid of the "file not found" errors. But nothing else changes.

Could somebody please explain what I am doing wrong ? The LNK2038 info on the website does not help me:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 7 of the instructions you linked to [here](http://programmingknowledgeblog.blogspot.de/2013/04/compiling-and-integrating-crypto-into.html) appear to be strange.  Normally you'd select `/MD` and `/MDd` for Release and Debug respectively, *or* you'd select `/MT` and `/MTd`.

The crux is that you have your Release build of crypto linked to the Dynamic version of the C Runtime Library (via `/MD`), but your test exe is set to link to the Static version (via `/MT`).

You should only link to a single version of the CRT - i.e. recompile crypto++ in Release mode with `/MT` set instead of `/MD`, or change your test exe to use `/MD`.

For further info on these flags, see the [msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Who wants to run crypto++ on linux(I did on ubuntu), after downloading library via apt-get install, should add to pro file this:
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/crypto++ -lcrypto++
Good luck!